# Yii 2 Active Record hasMany with LeftJoin

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

Having some trouble with Yii2's Active Record.

I would like to set a hasMany relation that includes a left join, however when doing so the record is populated with only a single relation object.

Here is the current code - copy pasting the executed query from Yii debug into navicat definitely returns multiple results.

```
public function getx()
{

    return $this->hasMany(x::className(),['x' => 'x'])
        ->viaTable('a', ['arId' => 'arId'], function ($query){


            $query->leftJoin('a b', 'a.type = b.type AND a.val < b.val')
                ->andWhere('a.foo IN (0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('a.bar IN ((0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('a.moo IN ((0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('b.val IS NULL');
        }
        );

}
```

The following code however works fine (Granted the queries are different).

```
    return $this->hasMany(x::className(),['x' => 'x'])
        ->viaTable('a', ['arId' => 'arId'], function ($query){

            $query->andWhere(['and', ['foo' => [0,1,2,3]],
                    ['bar' => [0,1,2,3]],
                    ['moo' => [0,1,2,3]],
                ]
                );
            }
        );
```

It is being called in the controller with the following:

```
$rs = ar::find(1)->with('x')->all();
```

The issue is clearly the join - can anyone enlighten me as to why this is the case?

Comment: can you use debugger and create breakpoint to see the `SQL` command that `leftJoin` is creating???

Comment: Yes, in the yii debugger, it shows the full query and pasting it into navicat gives me the desired results, ie. is returning multiple rows.

Comment: to be honest i dont know how that `leftjoin` works as you are passing 2 table names a and b without any separator or anything. Give me some time and let me try demo in my project and will get back to you.

Comment: It is left joining the same table (from `viatable()`) on itself (table name `a` with alias `b`). Appreciate you taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this as this one is work for me

```
public function getx()
{

    return $this->hasMany(x::className(), ['xId' => 'xId'])
                         ->leftJoin('a b', 'a.type = b.type AND a.val < b.val', 
                        function($query){
                            '..here you can add more join'
                        })
                        ->andWhere('a.foo IN (0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('a.bar IN ((0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('a.moo IN ((0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('b.val IS NULL');   

}
```

Please let me know if this get any problem as, i say again it is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

So here's the answer!

If there is a join you need specify an indexBy() as other wise the following code:

`db\ActiveQuery ln 224`

```
    if (!empty($this->join) && $this->indexBy === null) {
        $models = $this->removeDuplicatedModels($models);
    }
```

will send you into the `removeDuplicatedModels()` function.

This function checks for the primary key from the `modelclass` param, and then removes any duplicates. The junction table however is expecting multiple primaries (from parent Active Record) for this as it is a `hasMany()` relationship. Thus you need to override this check by setting the `indexBy` param to the desired primary key.

The below code will works:

```
public function getx()
{

    return $this->hasMany(x::className(),['xId' => 'xId'])
        ->viaTable('a', ['arId' => 'arId'], function ($query){
            $query->leftJoin('a b', 'a.type = b.type AND a.val < b.val')
                ->andWhere('a.foo IN (0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('a.bar IN ((0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('a.moo IN ((0,1,2,3)')
                ->andWhere('b.val IS NULL')
                ->indexBy('xId')
        }
        );

}
```